# Define Latex packages in reST file

Tags: latex, restructuredtext, tex, docutils, dexy

We used `Docutils` to produce reST document, and then make a TeX file via `rst2latex`.

In the `rst` file, we have added a lot of LaTeX code like:

```
.. raw:: latex

    ~\\
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    ~\\
```

But I do not know where to add packages like `\usepackage{tabulary}`.

If I add it in the `rst` file like I've shown above, even in the very beginning, this `\usepackage` line is automatically added after `\begin{document}` in the tex output file. This obviously generates an error.

Any idea where can I add `\usepackage` commands in reST?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [LaTeX preamble](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/latex.html) (after Docutils 0.7) by

```
rst2latex foo.rst foo.tex --latex-preamble="\usepackage{tabulary}"
```

which will generate the following in `foo.html`

```
%%% Custom LaTeX preamble
\usepackage{tabulary}
```

Alternatively, a custom stylesheet can be provided by

```
rst2latex foo.rst foo.tex --stylesheet=preamble.tex
```

which will generate

```
%%% User specified packages and stylesheets
\input{preamble.tex}
```

in the right place.